# Android Animation doesn't start until second touch

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have an animation when you click on the red button on the right(area 2). When you click on the button there starts no animation. When you click on a part in area 1 the animation starts.
I don't know what I do wrong. Anyone a solution?

Animation: rotate.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="100"
    android:fillAfter="true">
</rotate>
```

Java-code to start animation:

```
Animation animturn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate);
v.setAnimation(animturn);
animturn.start();
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you instead do `v.startAnimation(animturn)`?

Comment: Good answer! Thanks:) do you know what's the difference between startanimation and the way I worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try with Invalidate()  your View (v) after start() :

```
...
animturn.start();
v.Invalidate();
```